# Wordpress child theme breaks site appearance

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, parent-child

I am using **Splash theme** from StylemixThemes. I am trying to create a child theme in order to edit some things but when I am activating it I do not get the same result as the parent theme.

Inside the child theme folder I have the *style.css* and the *functions.php*. Here is the *functions.php* code

```
 <?php

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_styles'); function enqueue_parent_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css'); }
```

I am attaching a screenshot for both parent and child theme to show the difference.

[parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDbn.png)

[child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0rwZ.png)

I am wondering if there is a solution or if there is something I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there no child theme included? Most premium themes from ThemeForest come with a default child theme.

Comment: It's StylemixThemes I am sorry. Yes it provides a child theme but there is the exact same result.

Comment: Did you have issues importing your data?  The two pages don't match, styles aside.

Comment: This preview is from the theme's demo. I haven't imported any personal data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom child theme learning from [wpbeginner.com](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/)